# How to increment the filename number if the file exists

Tags: java, android

How can I increment the filename if the file already exists?

Here's the code that I am using -

```
int num = 0;

String save = at.getText().toString() + ".jpg";

File file = new File(myDir, save);

if (file.exists()) {
    save = at.getText().toString() + num + ".jpg";

    file = new File(myDir, save);
    num++;
}
```

This code works, but only two files are saved, like *file.jpg* and *file2.jpg*.

Comment: You can accept an answer if you feel your query is resolved.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This problem is to always initialize `num = 0`, so if `file` exists, it saves `file0.jpg` and does not check whether `file0.jpg` exists.

So, to code work. You should check until it is available:

```
int num = 0;
String save = at.getText().toString() + ".jpg";
File file = new File(myDir, save);
while(file.exists()) {
    save = at.getText().toString() + (num++) + ".jpg";
    file = new File(myDir, save);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Woks Perfecct! :)

Answer (score 2):

Having needed to solve this problem in my own code, I took [Tejas Trivedi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314177/how-to-increment-filename-if-file-exists/55107414#55107414), made it work like Windows when you happen to download the same file several times.

```
// This function will iteratively to find a unique file name to use when given a file: example (###).txt
// More or less how Windows will save a new file when one already exists: 'example.txt' becomes 'example (1).txt'.
// if example.txt already exists
private File getUniqueFileName(File file) {
    File originalFile = file;
    try {
        while (file.exists()) {
            String newFileName = file.getName();
            String baseName = newFileName.substring(0, newFileName.lastIndexOf("."));
            String extension = getExtension(newFileName);

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("( \\(\\d+\\))\\."); // Find ' (###).' in the file name, if it exists
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newFileName);

            String strDigits = "";
            if (matcher.find()) {
                baseName = baseName.substring(0, matcher.start(0)); // Remove the (###)
                strDigits = matcher.group(0); // Grab the ### we'll want to increment
                strDigits = strDigits.substring(strDigits.indexOf("(") + 1, strDigits.lastIndexOf(")")); // Strip off the ' (' and ').' from the match
                // Increment the found digit and convert it back to a string
                int count = Integer.parseInt(strDigits);
                strDigits = Integer.toString(count + 1);
            } else {
                strDigits = "1"; // If there is no (###) match then start with 1
            }
            file = new File(file.getParent() + "/" + baseName + " (" + strDigits + ")" + extension); // Put the pieces back together
        }
        return file;
    } catch (Error e) {
        return originalFile; // Just overwrite the original file at this point...
    }
}

private String getExtension(String name) {
    return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

Calling `getUniqueFileName(new File('/dir/example.txt')` when 'example.txt' already exists while generate a new File targeting '/dir/example (1).txt' if that too exists it'll just keep incrementing number between the parentheses until a unique file is found, if an error happens, it'll just give the original file name.

I hope this helps some one needing to generate a unique file in Java on Android or another platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(myDir, at.getText().toString() + ".jpg"); 

for (int num = 0; file.exists(); num++) {
    file = new File(myDir, at.getText().toString() + num + ".jpg");
}

// Now save/use your file here
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer, I made some more changes:

```
private File getUniqueFileName(String folderName, String searchedFilename) {
    int num = 1;
    String extension = getExtension(searchedFilename);
    String filename = searchedFilename.substring(0, searchedFilename.lastIndexOf("."));
    File file = new File(folderName, searchedFilename);
    while (file.exists()) {
        searchedFilename = filename + "(" + (num++) + ")" + extension;
        file = new File(folderName, searchedFilename);
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: private String getExtension(String name) {
        return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
    }

Comment: you might want to add that method to your answer. And what if file has no extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
String save = at.getText().toString();
String filename = save +".jpg";
File f = new File(filename);
while (f.exists()) {
    i++;
    filename =save+ Integer.toString(i)+".jpg";
    f = new File(filename);
}
f.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the code repetition of some of the answers here by using a `do while` loop

Here's an example using the newer NIO Path API introduced in Java 7

```
Path candidate = null;
int counter = 0;
do {
    candidate = Paths.get(String.format("%s-%d",
            path.toString(), ++counter));
} while (Files.exists(candidate));
Files.createFile(candidate);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin version:

```
private fun checkAndRenameIfExists(name: String): File {
    var filename = name
    val extension = "pdf"
    val root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
    var file = File(root, "$filename.$extension")
    var n = 0
    while (file.exists()) {
        n += 1
        filename = "$name($n)"
        file = File(root, appDirectoryName + File.separator + "$filename.$extension")
    }
    return file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I use to handle this case. It works for folders as well as for files.

```
var destination = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "MyFolder")

if (!destination.exists()) {
    destination.mkdirs()
} else {
    val numberOfFileAlreadyExist =
        destination.listFiles().filter { it.name.startsWith("MyFolder") }.size
    destination = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
        "MyFolder(${numberOfFileAlreadyExist + 1})"
    )
    destination.mkdirs()
}
```

Comment: what is  it.name.   here ?

Comment: "it" is a File object because, the `listFiles()`return a collection of File. So in the predicate of filter function extension, I can check for each file inside the collection if the file name match with my condition. In this case, for each file inisde the collection I check if the file name start with "MyFolder"

Answer (score 0):

Another simple logic solution to get the unique file name under a directory using Apache [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) using `WildcardFileFilter` to match the file name and get the number of exists with the given name and increment the counter.

```java
public static String getUniqueFileName(String directory, String fileName) {
  String fName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
  Collection<File> listFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(directory), new WildcardFileFilter(fName + "*", IOCase.INSENSITIVE), DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
  if(listFiles.isEmpty()) {
    return fName;
  }
  return fName.concat(" (" + listFiles.size() + ")");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This function returns the *exact* new file with an increment number for all kind of extensions.

```
private File getFileName(File file) {
    if (file.exists()) {
        String newFileName = file.getName();
        String simpleName = file.getName().substring(0, newFileName.indexOf("."));
        String strDigit = "";

        try {
            simpleName = (Integer.parseInt(simpleName) + 1 + "");
            File newFile = new File(file.getParent() + "/" + simpleName + getExtension(file.getName()));
            return getFileName(newFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }

        for (int i=simpleName.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(simpleName.charAt(i))) {
                strDigit = simpleName.substring(i + 1);
                simpleName = simpleName.substring(0, i+1);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (strDigit.length() > 0) {
            simpleName = simpleName + (Integer.parseInt(strDigit) + 1);
        }
        else {
            simpleName += "1";
        }

        File newFile = new File(file.getParent() + "/" + simpleName + getExtension(file.getName()));
        return getFileName(newFile);
    }
    return file;
}

private String getExtension(String name) {
    return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

Comment: What if there is no extension?